# Zend Router, variable number of URL parts

Tags: zend-framework, router

I am using routes in Zend Framework 1.
Currently I'm having a number of nested categories, all displayed in the URL. An URL can be of the following forms:

- www.example.com/category/1-category/2-subcategory/3-subsubcategory
- www.example.com/category/4-category/5-subcategory
- www.example.com/category/6-category

And longer.. Here 1 is a root category, with 2 being a child and 3 a grandchild. I am only interested in the ID of the last child in the URL, which are 3, 5 and 6 above.

I can't find a nice way to handle all URLs.

I've declared some routes in the Bootstrap file (only displaying the routes, not the full declarations):

- /category/:c/:a/:t/:e/g:/:category
- /category/:c/:a/:t/:e/:category
- /category/:c/:a/:t/:category
- /category/:c/:a/:category
- /category/:c/:category

In this order, the right route will be picked with the category variable sent to the controller, giving me the result I want. However, all declarations are the same and take up 6 lines of code, only differing one variable.

This results in a very ugly piece of code, but I can't find a way to write this nicely. Is there a nice way?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to define less number of routes in bootstrap than you can use * for dynamic routes but some times dynamic routes become less user friendly. For example:

```
/category/:c/:category/*
```